# Run Configuration

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I'm a new to Intellij + Gradle integration. I created a sample Java gradle project. When I create a new Configuration to try run my test main, it automatically make it a gradle task. Say if I want to run the Configuration as Java command line, instead of gradle task, is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ + Gradle does not create new gradle tasks in this case - IntelliJ is using the Gradle integration and knows how to create a configuration that you can run from Gradle. If you want to run the unit tests with Gradle from the command line, here are a few examples:

```
# Executes all tests in SomeTestClass
gradle test --tests SomeTestClass

# Executes a single specified test in SomeTestClass
gradle test --tests SomeTestClass.someSpecificMethod

gradle test --tests SomeTestClass.*someMethod*
```

More can be found on the [Gradle website](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple "Application" configuration as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Platform runner to **IntelliJ IDEA** (instead of Gradle) as to be used as default when you run a configuration in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Delegate settings | **Build and run using** setting.